# GCDAsyncSocket 2 requests at same time?

Tags: objective-c

Using the `GCDAsyncSocket` class, i know that there is a queue when asking to write 2 times to server , but we can see that if we have 2 requests , that the first one is a file, and the second is a string, server gets the file but never get the string after it .
if we write 2 strings ,it DO work.

I guess that the file takes times so the string is missing somewhere in the middle , or that he put it together with the file  ?
(each request is work alone).

this is the 2 requests: (first is a image file, second is the string )

```
[asyncSocket  writeData: [self setProtocolDataForImage:[[image copy] autorelease] WithCommand:5] withTimeout:-1 tag:-1];

[asyncSocket  writeData: [self setProtocolDataForString:[[user copy] autorelease] WithCommand:4] withTimeout:-1 tag:-1];
```